# Gnuplot - can "smooth frequency" work whole file (including multiple datablocks/indices)

Tags: gnuplot

**Situation**

Two metering devices (A, B) give data like

```
# meter A
time1 14.5
time2 9.3
time3 11.1
…
```

Thanks to some "binning" the timestamps from A and B might be identical (think of ice cream cones of different flavours sold per hour).

**Aim**

To get the total amount vs. time I'd like to use "smooth frequency", which should do what I want to achieve.

**Already tried**

Both "binned" datasets are "plotted" (set table $DB) into a internal here-document or temp-file on disk. But the datasets are separated by blank lines.

```
# meter A  
time1 14.5  
time2 9.3  
time3 11.1
    …


# meter B
time2 8.2
time3 2.8
...
```

Is it possible to use "smooth frequency" with the whole datafile to get something like

```
# meter A+B
time1 14.5  
time2 17.5
time3 13.9
    …
```

using only gnuplot? If so - how?

NB: The solution should work under windows, an installation of additional software is not possible. (Worst case: plot the combined data into a file and remove the blank lines in an editor...)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer my own question since right now my problem seems to be solved.

**Data setup**

```
File: "A.dat"
```

```
2.3 8.2
3 7
4.3 6.3


1 9
3.3 7.3
2 8
4 6
1.3 9.1
```

```
File: "B.dat"
```

```
1.1 1.1
3 3
3.1 3.3
2 2


1 1
4.1 4.4
2.1 2.1
4 4
```

My solution relies heavily on "in-memory-files" (here-docs), but I assume (not testet!) it works with temporary files on disk as well.

The following script may not be very sophisticated, but it's working:

```
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:*]

# simple binnig function (good enough for this demo)
binwidth = 1.0
bin(x) = binwidth * floor(x/binwidth)

# transfer original data to in-memory-files
set table $A_orig
  plot "A.dat" with table
unset table

set table $B_orig
  plot "B.dat" with table
unset table

# binning into new in-memory-file
set table $A_bin
  plot $A_orig using (bin($1)):2
unset table

set table $B_bin
  plot $B_orig using (bin($1)):2
unset table

# using in memory-files
# unique-filter: x -> avg(y)
set table $A_uniq
  plot $A_bin smooth unique
unset table

set table $B_uniq
  plot $B_bin smooth unique
unset table

# unite the different 'uniqued' datasets
# important: use plotstyle "with table"!
set table $AB_unite
  plot $A_uniq with table, \
       $B_uniq with table
unset table

# apply smooth frequency (x->sum(y))
set table $AB_tmp
  plot $AB_unite smooth freq
unset table
# create final in-memory-file
set table $AB_freq  
  plot $AB_tmp with table
unset table

# plot all results
plot $A_orig with points pointsize 2 title "A (original)", \
     $B_orig with points title "B (original)", \
     $A_bin with points title "A (binned)", \
     $B_bin with points title "B (binned)", \
     $A_uniq with linespoints title "A (binned,unique)", \
     $B_uniq with linespoints title "B (binned,unique)", \
     $AB_freq with linespoints title "A+B (binned,unique,frequency)"

# clean
undef $A_*
undef $B_*
undef $AB_*
```

The important trick is not only to use "**set table**", but finding out when to use  plotstyle "**with table**" as well.